# A question concerning separate and joint continuity of bilinear maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, reference-request

Suppose that $V$ is a locally convex topological vector space and $f:V^2 \to V$ is a bilinear map.  Suppose that $C \subseteq V$ is compact and convex, $f$ maps $C^2$ into $C$ and
$f \restriction C^2$ is separately continuous.
Must $f \restriction C^2$ be jointly continuous?

In the particular application I have in mind, $V = \ell_\infty^*$ with the weak* topology.
Moreover the function $f$ is injective.
I suspect even in this setting that this is false.

I am also interested in a good reference for the optimal results of concerning separate and joint continuity of bilinear maps.
Ideally this would be written for someone who is not a functional analyst.

Answer (score 9):

A personal obsession is (weakly) almost period functions.  Let $G$ be a discrete group (you can work more generally) and for $f\in \ell^\infty(G)$ let $O(f)$ be the set of translate of $f$ by the group action.  Set
$$ AP(G) = \{ f\in \ell^\infty(G) : O(f)\text{ is relatively compact}\} \\$$
$$WAP(G) = \{ f\in \ell^\infty(G) : O(f)\text{ is weakly relatively compact}\}$$

Then these are unital sub-$C^*$-algebras of $\ell^\infty(G)$ and so have character spaces $G^{AP}$ and $G^{WAP}$.  You can extend the product from $G$ to these: then the product on $G^{AP}$ is jointly continuous, but that on $G^{WAP}$ only separately jointly continuous.  Translated back to algebra, this means that the measure spaces $M(G^{AP})$ and $M(G^{WAP})$ become Banach algebras for the convolution product.  The continuity translates to say that the product on $M(G^{WAP})$ is separately weak$^*$-continuous, and that on $M(G^{AP})$ is even jointly weak$^*$-continuous on bounded sets.

So that gives an example: if $C$ is the closed unit ball of $M(G^{WAP})$ and $f$ is the product map, then $f$ satisfies your requirements, but $f$ is not jointly continuous unless $WAP(G) = AP(G)$ (I think-- this last claim needs a little chasing of definitions).  If $G$ is abelian then $G^{AP}$ is the classical Bohr compacitification, but $G^{WAP}$ is much larger.  There are books by Berglund (and coauthors) on this topic; they do, IMHO, need a functional analysis background.

Surely there are easier examples for what you want though.  (And $f$ is not injective in my example).

Comment: Thanks.  This is in the spirit of what I was lookng for.