# A unital algebra with norm and continuous multiplication is a Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

In my research in functional analysis, I came across this rather simple result:

> For a normed algebra A over $ \mathbb{C} $ with unit, in which multiplication , right and left are both continuous w.r.t the norm defined, such that A with this norm is a Banach space, there exists an equivalent norm with respect to which A is a Banach Algebra.

I was wondering, is the existence of a unit in A truly necessary, or can we guarantee the existence of an equivalent norm such that A is a Banach algebra?

Comment: Do you mean, *in which multiplication (right and left) is continuous*?

Comment: @DavidHandelman : Yes sir, please forgive my carelessness

Comment: No, unit serves to ensure that the left (resp. right) regular rep. is _faithful_. If your Banach algebra has no zero divisor the statement works (with only _one_ multiplication).

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Can we not take the representation of $A$ on $A\oplus {\bf C}$ to get a faithful representation, and hence an equivalent norm that is submultiplicative?

Comment: @YemonChoi Of course, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ***no*** (a unit is not necessary within the algebra). 
In the case the product is continuous (i.e. there exists $M>0$ such that, identically, $||xy||\leq M||x||.||y||$ see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60953/a-question-concerning-separate-and-joint-continuity-of-bilinear-maps)) and of a unital algebra, the common way to construct a multiplicative norm equivalent to the given one is to consider the left-regular representation i.e. $s\rightarrow \gamma(s)$ where $\gamma(s)\in \mathcal{L}_A$ is defined by $\gamma(s)[x]=sx$ and setting the new norm $||s||':=|||\gamma(s)|||$ (the last norm being that of the *bounded convergence* within $\mathcal{L}_A$). In this respect, the representation $s\rightarrow \gamma(s)$ must be *faithful* (it is the case, in particular, when $A$ is unital but not only). If it is not, then $||\ ||_1$ is only a seminorm. Following Yemon's comment, in the case when the given algebra is not unital, a way to circumvent this is to consider the left-regular $s\rightarrow \gamma_1(s)$ representation of $A$ on the Banach space $A\oplus\mathbb{C}$ (endowed, for example, with the norm $||x+\lambda||_1=||x||+|\lambda|$). This representation is given by $\gamma_1(s)[x+\lambda]=sx+\lambda.s$. It is an easy exercise to prove that the new seminorm $||s||'':=|||\gamma_1(s)|||$ is, in any case, a norm equivalent to the given one. Hope that it helps.

Comment: I don't understand: I thought the answer to the _given_ question is yes. Certainly we in BA world believe that if one has a Banach space, equipped with an algebra product that is continous, then this space can be renormed with an equivalent norm such that one gets a Banach algebra in the usual sense.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: I read it this way: The OP asks if a unit is necessary for the existence of an equivalent multiplicative norm and Duchamp Gérard H. E.s answer says "No, a unit is not necessary - such  norm always exists".

Comment: @ToddLeason I see what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, Todd is right in his interpretation of my ambiguous "no". I made it precise.

Comment: In this and in many other cases on OM, a simple answer **y/n** is not easy to interpret. There are still many other answers that no answer in the "Answer" is formulated. I feel that an answer should alway include **the full statement** of its result **explicitly**. Preferably, most of the time, an answer should **start** with the explicit full statement of its result.